# How do I add an event listener using MSHTML's addEventListener in IE9?

Tags: c#, mshtml, internet-explorer-9, addeventlistener, iwebbrowser2

The MSDN documentation for [`addEventListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975825%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says it accepts a callback function in the form of an `IDispatch *` object. From C# (I'm using COM interop), Visual Studio displays the parameter type as just `object`.

I looked for an `IEventListener` interface or something similar but didn't find one. What am I supposed to pass in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I learned that these COM connection points (event handlers) are specified with `DispId(0)`. Callback functions are represented by instances of classes like:

```
// These attributes may be optional, depending on the project configuration.
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class EventListener
{
    [DispId(0)]
    // The "target" parameter is an implementation detail.
    public void NameDoesNotMatter(object target, IDOMEvent evt) { ... }
}
```

Since `DispId(0)` specifies the default method to invoke, the actual name of the method doesn't matter. However, the method parameters certainly do matter. For example, `IHTMLElement.onclick` must be assigned a callback with no arguments, while `IHTMLElement2.attachEvent` takes a callback with one parameter of type `IHTMLEventObj` (or `IHTMLEventObj2`, ..., `6` , or even just `object`).

In summary, COM `IDispatch` callbacks can be implemented in C# using a COM-visible class with a method that accepts the correct arguments and is annotated with `[DispId(0)]`.

---

Despite all of this, solutions that avoid the W3C DOM Events API may be more appropriate, as IE9 DOM objects do not support this method when the browser is using a lower document mode for compatibility. For example, an extension that uses `addEventListener` will fail on a page like Bing, which is rendered in IE7 mode.

It also doesn't seem possible to set the document mode used by an `IWebBrowser2` instance aside from manually doing it through the F12 developer tools.