# How do I add an event listener to my button created in C# for IE BHO?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, mshtml

In my IE BHO I create a input button element using:

```
    var button = doc.createElement("input");
    button.setAttribute("value", "myButton"); //next line gets an error
    button.addEventListener("click", openFunction, false); //openFunction is a function inside of the same class
```

When I try to call button.addEventListener I get a 'mshtml.IHTMLElement' does not contain a definition for 'addEventListener' error. I find this odd because according to this site (http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php) I should be in the clear.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999247/how-do-i-add-an-event-listener-using-mshtmls-addeventlistener-in-ie9) thread but it seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Had to use similar method to the thread I linked in original question.

```
/// Inside the BHO.cs file and in my namespace
/// Generic HTML DOM Event method handler.
///
public delegate void DHTMLEvent(IHTMLEventObj e);

///
/// Generic Event handler for HTML DOM objects.
/// Handles a basic event object which receives an IHTMLEventObj which
/// applies to all document events raised.
///
public class DHTMLEventHandler
{
    public DHTMLEvent Handler;
    HTMLDocument Document;

    public DHTMLEventHandler(HTMLDocument doc)
    {
        this.Document = doc;
    }
    [DispId(0)]
    public void Call()
    {
        Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);
    }
}
    public void BrowserEventHandler(IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.type == "click" && e.srcElement.id == "IDOfmyButton")
            {
                // do something.
                something();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
```

Inside my OnDocumentComplete method (also in same namespace as above [extra info for novices]):

```
            DHTMLEventHandler myHandler = new DHTMLEventHandler(framedoc);
            myHandler.Handler += new DHTMLEvent(this.BrowserEventHandler);
            button.onclick = myHandler;
```

A lot of work just to get a button to click. In firefox it was one line :O